# MLFLOW: Shell not configured error when using conda.yaml environment

Tags: conda, mlflow

I am getting the following error when using the `mlflow run` command without `--no-conda` option. I have tried the suggestions provided in the error message but no luck. I tried activating conda environment using `conda activate` and it works. But, it does not work when using through mlflow. Is there any way I can edit the command that mlflow executes in the background?

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda 
activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.
To initialize your shell, run
$ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
```

Comment: Have you checked whether there is a newer version of mlflow that knows how to work with the latest conda?

Comment: I am using MLflow 1.0.0. It does have support for conda. I think the problem is with the windows cmd terminal and mlflow.

Answer (score 1):

MLflow 1.1 has addressed this issue.

https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst